# operand type clash uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int when trying to add 'ALL' option to my parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I created a drop down menu by getting values from the query. Now, I am trying to add "All" as the option instead of using multi select. I want the user either to select "All" or 1. Below is the query I am using and I run into this error message

operand type clash uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

```
 select departmentid, name from department
 union
 select -1, 'ALL'
```

How can I add 'ALL' option and not run into this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `NULL` instead?

```
select NULL, 'ALL'
```

Or generating an id on the fly?

```
select newid(), 'ALL'
```

Comment: I am using newid() method, but when I select the option is doesnt produce any data

Comment: I tried using Null instead and it doesn't produce any data as well